Error IM006 [SQLSTATE]: Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed when connecting to SQL Server using PHP and ODBC
I am trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server database using PHP and ODBC. However, I encounter the following error:
Array (
[0] => Array (
    [0] => IM006
    [SQLSTATE] => IM006
    [1] => 0
    [code] => 0
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
    [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed
)
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 01000
    [SQLSTATE] => 01000
    [1] => 5701
    [code] => 5701
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'TclStsDB'.
    [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed database context to 'TclStsDB'.
)
[2] => Array (
    [0] => 01000
    [SQLSTATE] => 01000
    [1] => 5703
    [code] => 5703
    [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
    [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Changed language setting to us_english.
)

)
What does the error IM006 [SQLSTATE] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed indicate, and how can I resolve it?
**

NOTE:

**
<?php

$serverName = "WIN-8OA3CCQAE4D"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication. array( "Database"=>"TclStsDB");
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TclStsDB", "UID"=>"admin", "PWD"=>"Pl@yOn24@dm!n@2kEBD");
$con = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $con ) {
     //echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}


?>

This is my connection code.

Please include the code that you're using to connect to SQL Server.  What is your connectionString like?

Please put that in your post and not in the comments.
